# How to access files, created by Laravel Sail with PhpStorm?

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, laravel-sail

In the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/installation#getting-started-on-windows) there are instruction on how to work with Laravel Sail files with VSCode. How can I access files with PhpStorm?

Answer (score 0):

In PhpStorm, you can directly open a project stored in the WSL file system and work with it like with any other project.

1. Click **Open** on the Welcome screen or select **File | Open** from the main menu.
2. In the Select Path dialog that opens, select the folder in the WSL file system that contains the project to open, or type the path to the **`\\wsl$`** project location manually.

[image]